# req_type wise count id in one query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have an sql query problem . I don't want to execute three times query for same result.

In my table I have one field `req_type` which have three parameter ,
either 1, either 2, either 3 .

I want counter based on req_type in one query instead of by executing query 3 times like below

```
select count(id) as premium FROM tablename where req_type=1
select count(id) as premium1 FROm tablename where req_type=2
select count(id) as premium2 FROm tablename where req_type=3
```

I am stuck , can anybody help me?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `case` for such type of count

```
select sum(case when req_type=1 then 1 else 0 end) as premium,
sum(case when req_type=2 then 1 else 0 end) as premium1,
sum(case when req_type=3 then 1 else 0 end) as premium2
FROM tablename
```

Answer (score 1):

Use one query instead of threes by using `group by` cluase

```
select req_type , count(id) as premium 
FROM tablename 
where req_type in (1,2,3)
group by req_type
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT req_type, COUNT(id) AS count_premium
FROM tablename
GROUP BY req_type;
```